# Maven Environment

Tags: java, java-ee

Я использую для сборки проекта maven. библиотеки добавляю по dependancy в файл pom.xml. Потом  когда создаю jar-файл приложения запускаю скрипт `mvn compile assembly:single` который собирает проект с используемыми библиотеками, jar-ники которых я даже не знаю где лежат.

Допустим я хочу выкачать библиотеку не по dependancy, а просто zip файл. Предположиv hibernante. Как  правильно настроить  environment.

В туториале написано следующие

> Now copy all the library files from /lib into your CLASSPATH, and
>   change your classpath variable to include all the JARs:
>
> Finally copy hibernate3.jar file into your CLASSPATH. This file lies
>   in the root directory of the installation and is the primary JAR that
>   Hibernate needs to do its work.

И куда нужно поместить файл конфиграции

file **hibernate.cfg.xml** is kept in the root directory of your application's classpath.

Answer (score 4):

Когда вы запускаете сборку проекта, Maven сначала проверяет наличие объявленных зависимостей и плагинов в вашем локальном репозитории, который находится в директории `$HOME/.m2`. Если там их нет, то он скачивает их из [центрального репозитория](http://search.maven.org/) Также можно объявить [дополнительные репозитории](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).

> Допустим я хочу выкачать библиотеку не по dependancy, а просто zip
>   файл

Покажите, где вы видели Java библиотеку в виде ZIP файла. В этом формате распростаняются не библиотеки, а дистрибутивы. Т.е сама библиотека в виде JAR, плюс документация, демо, конфиги, README и т.п

[Установить файл в локальный репозиторий](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) Maven можно вручную.

> И куда нужно поместить файл конфиграции

Конфигурационный файл должен быть в classpath. Обычно кладут `src/main/resources`. После сборки проекта, все содержимое этой директории попадает в classpath. Но, при желании, с помощью плагина, при сборке проекта можно скопировать этот файл в classpath из любой директории.

Answer (score -2):

Открываете свойства проекта и там есть раздел Deployment Assembly в нем жмете add и выбираете свою библиотеку или папку с ресурсами или что душа пожелает.